# Block Windows 10 Shutdown with Python 3

Tags: python, windows

Is there any way to prevent Windows from shutting down my system with Python. So I can't shutdown my system while my Python script is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there is.

from windows docs

> **Shutdown Notifications**
>
> Applications with a window and message queue
> receive shutdown notifications through the WM_QUERYENDSESSION and
> WM_ENDSESSION messages. These applications should return TRUE to
> indicate that they can be terminated. Applications should not block
> system shutdown unless it is absolutely necessary. Applications should
> perform any required cleanup while processing WM_ENDSESSION.
> Applications that have unsaved data could save the data to a temporary
> location and restore it the next time the application starts. It is
> recommended that applications save their data and state frequently;
> for example, automatically save data between save operations initiated
> by the user to reduce the amount of data to be saved at shutdown.
> Console applications receive shutdown notifications in their handler
> routines. To register a console handler, use the SetConsoleCtrlHandler
> function. Service applications receive shutdown notifications in their
> handler routines. To register a service control handler, use the
> RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx function.
>
> **Blocking Shutdown**
>
> If an application must block a potential system shutdown, it can call the
> ShutdownBlockReasonCreate function. The caller provides a reason
> string that will be displayed to the user. The reason string should be
> short and clear, providing the user with the information necessary to
> decide whether to continue shutting down the system.

so you have to intercept the WM_QUERYENDSESSION message and return False .

and doing some web search i found a discussion about that how to intercept the WM_QUERYENDSESSION in python :

> if you've built an app with a message loop, you can receive the
> WM_QUERYENDSESSION message. If you want to have a GUI, most GUI
> libraries will probably wrap this up in their own way. If you don't
> need a GUI, your simplest solution is probably to use PyWin32.
> Somewhere in the docs there's a tutorial on creating a hidden window
> and writing a simple message loop. Just do that on the main thread,
> and do your real work on a background thread, and signal your
> background thread when a WM_QUERYENDSESSION message comes in.
>
> Or, much more simply, just use SetConsoleCtrlHandler (again through
> PyWin32). This can also catch ^C, ^BREAK, and the user closing your
> console, as well as the logoff and shutdown messages that
> WM_QUERYENDSESSION catches. More importantly, it doesn't require a
> message loop, so if you don't have any other need for one, it's a lot
> simpler.

i can't help with code snippet as i don't have access to windows pc and i don't want to share code without testing, but i hope i pointed you to what you should look for.